# Proofs of Liouville Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

Are there proofs of Liouville theorem (bounded functions holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$ are constants) without using the Cauchy theorem?

Answer (score 3):

There is a proof [due to Nelson](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1961-012-06/S0002-9939-1961-0259149-4/S0002-9939-1961-0259149-4.pdf) that a bounded harmonic function is constant using the mean value properties of harmonic functions.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which Cauchy's theorem you are referring to, but if you allow the weaker one( i.e. cauchy's theorem for a circle contour. You only need Lebniz rule to prove this) , you can prove Liouville's theorem using the independence of path and Lebniz rule. Check out "Conway - Functions of one complex variable"